# How to save Google Cloud Datalab output into BigQuery using R

Tags: sql, r, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am using R in Google Cloud Datalab and I want to save my output, which is a table containing Strings that is created in the code itself, to BigQuery. I know there is a way to do it with Python by using `bqr_create_table` so I am looking for the equivalent in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this [blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/google-cloud-platform-for-data-scientists-using-r-with-google-bigquery-part-2-storing-and-retrieving-data-frames) from Gus Class on Google Cloud Platform which uses this code to write to BigQuery:

```
# Install BigRQuery if you haven't already...
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("rstats-db/bigrquery")
# library(bigrquery)
insert_upload_job("your-project-id", "test_dataset", "stash", stash)
```

Where `"test_dataset"` is the dataset in BigQuery, `"stash"` is the table inside the dataset and `stash` is any dataframe you have define with your data.

There is more information on how to authorize with [bigrquery](https://github.com/r-dbi/bigrquery)